# Need some assistance with moving an enemy bullet animation down the screen

Tags: java, animation, lwjgl, slick2d, bullet

I need help figuring out why the enemy bullets won't move when they have identical code... Please help... I didn't make either one as a separate class just simple animations

Now I think that you can see when I say they have identical code, I mean like IDENTICAL code haha. It's really throwing me off that the player bullets work fine but the enemy bullets won't do anything

```
public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
map.draw(0,0);
// First enemy
enemy1.draw(enemy1PosX, enemy1PosY);
enemyShot.draw(enemy1PosX+30, enemy1PosY + 65);


//Player
ship.draw(shipPosX, shipPosY);
playerShot.draw(shootPosX+23, shootPosY);
Animation copy = playerShot.copy();
copy.draw(shootPosX+23, shootPosY);

g.drawString("Ship X: " + shipPosX + "\nShips Y: " + shipPosY,400,20);

if(quit == true) {
    g.drawString("Resume (R)",250,100);
    g.drawString("Main Menu (M)",250,150);
    g.drawString("Quit Game(Q)",250,200);
    if(quit==false){
        g.clear();
    }

}
```

}

```
public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) throws SlickException {
Input input = gc.getInput();
//Move Enemy

enemy1=enemyA;
//enemy1PosX += delta * .7f;
//enemy1PosY += delta * .1f;
    if(enemy1PosX > 668){
        enemy1PosX = -1;
        if(isEnemyHit(enemy1)){
            deadEnemies.add(enemy1);
    }
}


// up
if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_UP)){
    ship = move;
    movefx.play();
    shipPosY -= delta * .6f;
    //collision detection
    if(shipPosY < 9){
        shipPosY = 9;

    }
}
//down
if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_DOWN)){
    ship = move;
    shipPosY += delta * .6f;
    //collision detection
    if(shipPosY > 468){
        shipPosY = 468;
    }
}
//left
if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_LEFT)){
    ship = move;
    shipPosX -= delta * .6f;
    //collision detection
    if(shipPosX < -1){
        shipPosX =-1;
    }
}
//right
if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_RIGHT)){
    ship = move;
    shipPosX += delta * .6f;

    //collision detection
    if(shipPosX > 668){
        shipPosX = 668;
    }
}
    //FIRE PLAYER BULLETS
    playerShot = shootUp;
    playerShot.start();
    shootPosX = shipPosX-10;
    shootPosY -= delta * 1.3f;
    Animation copy = playerShot.copy();

    //Auto-Shoot bullet
    if(shootPosY <= shipPosY - 480){
        copy = playerShot;
        shootPosX = shipPosX;
        shootPosY = shipPosY; 
        shootPosY -= delta * 1.7f;
        copy.restart();
    }

    //FIRE ENEMY BULLETS
    enemyShot = shootDown;
    enemyShot.start();
    enemyShotPosX = enemy1PosX + 10;
    enemyShotPosY += delta * .3f;
    Animation dbl = playerShot.copy();
```

EnemyShot is an Animation playerShot is an animation No seperate enemy or player class either. Please help

Comment: *"Need some assistance.."*  Need an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) & a question.

Comment: "I need help figuring out why the enemy bullets won't move when they have identical code." I did explain what I don't understand... The player bullets have the same code... the player bullets work the enemy bullets don't... I don't get how that's not explaining what I don't understand

Comment: Man I just came here hoping somebody better than me with java seeing as how I am a beginner at this can help me out

Comment: You're a grown man... why do you need a '?' to know the subject of the post... All I need is a little bit of help that's all...

Comment: So you're not going to help? All you just did instead of sharing knowledge was spark a little "argument" how's that helping...

Comment: childish, you vote it down for what reason?

Comment: Have you tried switching the ordering of the player and enemy animations? If the enemy bullet fires and the player's does not, there might be a transform that needs to be reset.

Comment: thank you for your help... I just tried it and no luck the image of the animation just sits at the X and Y position I set for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to give each individual enemy bullet it's own position, instead of one relative to the position of the enemy itself. This was inside of your render method:

```
enemyShot.draw(enemy1PosX+30, enemy1PosY + 65);
```

From what I understand, in the very best case scenario, this will make the bullet follow the enemies x and y position with a small amount of displacement. Also, you have the code that enables enemy movement commented, which is:
 `//enemy1PosX += delta * .7f;
//enemy1PosY += delta * .1f;` 
Hope this helps!